# Help with discrete probability distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

This problem is related to physics. Imagine you have discrete energy states that are equally spaced. I don't know how many energy states there are. However let's say there are n number of energy states.
I know about the discrete uniform distrubution.

But I want to know the equations for the probability distribution for the energy states when they are skewed to the left and right and for the aproximate bell curve.
[image]

Comment: The binomial distribution is discrete and is approximately normal for large $n$.

Comment: I think the value of n is very small probabily around 5